# How to convert a Dataset of PDFs to a Media Set?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I have a dataset of PDFs. I want to convert this dataset of raw files to a MediaSet.

I tried to convert the dataset of files in Code Repository but I'm unclear how to proceed and which code to use to perform this operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 main components:

- Media Sets (storage, you can see that as a dataset of raw files like PDFs, etc.)
- Media References (references files in a media set or a dataset with raw files)

#### Media Sets

In order to have a mediaset, there have multiple approaches:

1. Create a mediaset directly (Action > New > Mediaset). This creates a MediaSet which users with relevant permissions can upload to.
2. Directly create a mediaset from data ingest or equivalent (e.g. virtual storage ...)
3. Create a mediaset from a pipeline

You are in case 3. in those cases, because you already have a dataset with raw files. In a Code Repository, you need to import the `transforms-media` library in your code repository (via the left icon to [import any libraries](https://palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/use-python-libraries/))

To do so:

```py
from transforms.api import transform, Input
from transforms.mediasets import MediaSetOutput

@transform(
    output_mediaset=MediaSetOutput("<your path to mediaset>"),
    input_dataset=Input("<your path to dataset with raw files>")
)
def compute(input_dataset, output_mediaset):
    output_mediaset.put_dataset_files(input_dataset)
```

You can directly move to next step: create media references dataset from this raw dataset (would have been the same from a Media Set).

#### Media References

Now comes the question: How do you convert a media set into media references ?
[Multiple ways](https://palantir.com/docs/foundry/data-integration/media-sets/#transforms):

1. Via a Code Repository: A code example is available on the same page [a bit below](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/data-integration/media-sets/#media-references) to read a dataset of raw files and convert it to a media references.
2. Via Pipeline Builder: you need to add the mediaset containing the raw files, and to transform it using the `Get Media References (Datasets)`.

You should try approach 2. as it will be much simpler to achieve what you require here.

#### Do something with it

Once you have media references, you can use it in your Ontology etc.